# How do I determine the optimum variable weights when ranking the "best" candidate for a prize

Tags: php, symbolic-math, weighted

Consider I am writing a program to objectively select a winner in a competition.  There are 'n' human judges secretly assigning a 1st, 2nd, 3rd position ranking to the top three candidates from a pool of 'm' candidates.

The program must then go through the judges decisions, and based on weights assigned to 1st place, 2nd place and 3rd place, each candidate will be rated based on the number of 1st, 2nd, and 3rd place votes they received, multiplied by the appropriate rating for each finishing position.

However, at the start, the program has no idea of what weights are appropriate, so I have created an automated "program" that is intended to "discover" the proper weights based on how the judges would pick the winner from a hypothetical situation.

I present a table where the horizontal axis contains the finishing position, and the judges' codes (e.g. Judge W, Judge X, Judge Y, Judge Z).  The vertical axis has three rows (1st place, 2nd place, 3rd place), and at the intersection of each Judge/Row, I have randomly generated a candidate ID (from the set A through F).

After rendering the table, I then ask the judge who THEY would have chosen as the winner (the judge has the option to PASS if there is not sufficient information to choose).

After the judges run through an appropriate number of scenarios, I wish to now take the results of the various runs and use that information to determine the "best fit" for the weighting of 1st, 2nd, and 3rd positions.

Let's say one of the hypothetical grids looks like this:

```html
<table border="1"><tbody><tr><th>Position</th><th>Judge 'W'</th><th>Judge 'X'</th><th>Judge 'Y'</th><th>Judge 'Z'</th></tr><tr><td>1st</td><td><center>A</center></td><td><center>F</center></td><td><center>C</center></td><td><center>B</center></td></tr><tr><td>2nd</td><td><center>D</center></td><td><center>B</center></td><td><center>E</center></td><td><center>D</center></td></tr><tr><td>3rd</td><td><center>C</center></td><td><center>E</center></td><td><center>B</center></td><td><center>C</center></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

and the human judge picks candidate "B" as the winner.  My program should react by calculating the (w1 + w2 + w3) > (w1 + 2*w3)  (i.e. B better than C) and (w1 + w2 + w3) > (2* w2)  (i.e. B better than D), etc.

From these various algebraic comparisons, over a number of "hypothetical scenarios", I want to be able to calculate the optimum values for w1, w2 and w3.  And then, at some point when there is enough "good" data, I want to be able to use these "discovered" weights to go back over the training data an identify areas where perhaps the human judges were mistaken.

I am using PHP as the programming language and don't know which functions or possible existing libraries are appropriate to solve this kind of "fuzzy" equation.

I'm looking for some direction to help me tackle this problem.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Why not give hidden points to each top position for an easy ranking sorting ? 
First place = 8 points, second = 6, third = 4. So B hidden score would be 18 (8 + 6 + 4), C score = 16 (8 + 4 + 4). You don't have to show score to users, but in my opinion and if I well understand what you want, it's the best way to sort players !

Comment: Camille, you are correct about how the formula is calculated and totals are compared.  What I'm trying to do is discover those "point values" either algebraically or through iterative testing, rather than choosing arbitrary values.  The issue here is that "my" interpretation of who the winner should be (which would affect how I choose the point values) may not agree with the weighting system the judges are using.  I'm asking THEM to go through the hypothetical scenarios and assign winners so I can analyze who THEY think should win, and derive weights based on their input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the winning candidate count how many times he appears in each position, then do the same for all the other candidates. Then write the following formula for each candidate:

```
   GoodForJ=w1*nw1+w2*nw2+w3*nw3>w1*nj1+w2*nj2+w3*nj3
```

Where nw1-3 are the times the winner appears in each position and nj1-3 are the times the j candidate appears in each position.
If goodForJ is true for all the candidates this means that the tuple of weights is good. Now you just have to try a bounch of weights combinations and find out which one fits. Trying all combinations of weights between 1 and 10 requires 1000 iterations.
To make things a bit fuzzier, for each try you could count how many timrs goodForJ is true and choose the weights that produces the highest score.

Comment: let me thank you for taking the time to answer.  The approach you're suggesting is the programmatic approach I had started to code.  It's basically a trial-and-error methodology where, as you point out, you need to go through a relatively large number of iterations to "discover" the optimum set of weights.  I was hoping there was an algebraic formula I could use to minimize the computation time, since the number of training scenarios I have number in the thousands.  But, unless I hear something else, that's what I'm in the process of implementing.

Comment: Well, iterating through all possible values is just the naive approach. You could use the Newton method to make weights converge faster and more accurately. There could be even faster methods, like the ones used to extimate the cheapest path for multiple shipment delivery, but we must find out if and how to apply them to your scenario. I will think a bit about it.

Comment: Just an update.  I coded the iterative process and set what I considered to be a "reasonable" initial set of weights.  Using the analogy of GOLD, SILVER, BRONZE for the levels and the initial assumption that 2 medals of the next-lower level is slightly better than 1 medal of the higher level, I was able to achieve what may be an acceptable result.  I won't know for certain until I have more human-verified results.  But, I was able to identify cases where the human judging was clearly incorrect - human error being what it is, so I'm encouraged by initial results.  I have to read about Newton.

Comment: I read a bit about the Newton method and have a couple of questions.  First, I don't see how it could be applied to the concept of multiple simultaneous weights, since the function appears to be based on a single variable (unless that "single variable" can be a matrix).  Second, the FUNCTION isn't defined.  That's the problem I'm having to begin with.  I don't know what FUNCTION should be defined to solve my issue.  Regarding my intial assumption, it works if 2 SILVER are better than a GOLD, but are 4 BRONZE better than a GOLD?  I'm not sure about that.

Comment: To apply the Newton method you have to translate the above algorithm to a cost function, i.e. a function that says how much a tuple of weights is bad; this function has to be differentiable. Let's define our "partial" cost function:
`Cj=(w1*nj1+w2*nj2+w3*nj3)-(w1*nw1+w2*nw2+w3*nw3)`
the first block is the score of the Jth loser, the second block is the score of the winner. The greater the score of the winner the lower will be the cost. The total cost is just the sum of the costs for all the J losers. Let's set w3=1 and calculate w1 and w2 using 2D Newton method.